# refresh footer DIV on interval

Tags: javascript

I am having issues refreshing footer div on interval where mysql results display in footer

I currently have a page that display a 100 box table that loads on page load and refreshes on interval, I have tried to implement the same type of approach for the footer but get the error of unexpected token  <

The code im currently using to refresh the table is

```
        function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $.get('php/mysql.php', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item.beacon);
                //$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
            });
        });

    }
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 5000);
});


<script>
function updateFooter() {
<div id="footer">

<div class="box"><h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php           
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value1) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
echo "".$row['count(value1)'].""; 
}  
?></div>
<div class="box2"><h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php           
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value2) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
echo "".$row['count(value2)'].""; 
}  
?></div>
<div class="box3"><h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php           
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value3) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
echo "".$row['count(value3)'].""; 
}  
?></div>
<div class="box4"><h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php           
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value4) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
echo "".$row['count(value4)'].""; 
}  
?></div>
</div>
            });
    }
    var updateFooterInterval = setInterval(updateFooter, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's totally wrong way of combining JavaScript and HTML. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: which would be the better way of doing it as the updateTable works perfectly for me but the updateFooter doesnt

Comment: you should take a look at https://www.codecademy.com/ to learn the basics of html and javascript first. its for free ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Pure JavaScript, you cannot mix HTML and JS (React does that, anyway but it's RJX). In simple terms, have a separate PHP file for footer, say `footer.php` and in that, put the code you want to get updated:

```
<?php           
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
  echo "".$row['count(value)'].""; 
}  
?>
```

And then in your front end, use AJAX, preferably ([`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) to update:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="box">
    <h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
    <div class="footer-contents"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the above, use:

```
$(".footer-contents").load("footer.php");
setInterval(function () {
  $(".footer-contents").load("footer.php");
}, 5000);
```

The above will update the footer on an interval of 5 seconds.

Would be better idea to wrap inside the `document`'s ready function and adding `#footer` for additional specificity:

```
$(function () {
  $("#footer .footer-contents").load("footer.php");
  setInterval(function () {
    $("#footer .footer-contents").load("footer.php");
  }, 5000);
});
```

---

**Update:**

With this content being in the `footer.php`:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="box">
    <h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value1) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
  echo "".$row['count(value1)'].""; 
}  
?>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value2) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
  echo "".$row['count(value2)'].""; 
}  
?>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value3) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
  echo "".$row['count(value3)'].""; 
}  
?>
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <h6 align="center">Total count<h6>
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");  
$query = "SELECT count(value4) FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
  echo "".$row['count(value4)'].""; 
}  
?>
  </div>
</div>
```

You wouldn't need anything else from the above code.

Comment: if i was to add more than 1 value to the query how would i specify which value to return? e.g select value1, value2 from table

 then in   $("#footer .footer-contents").load("footer.php");
 load value2

Comment: @a.parkes You can talk to PHP from JavaScript using GET parameters. Use something like `footer.php?stuff=hello` and get it back in PHP by using `$_GET["stuff"]`.

Comment: is it possible you could provide an example please?

Comment: @a.parkes I just did above. Use `"footer.php?stuff=" + someJSvar` instead of `"footer.php"` and get the value in the backend PHP using `$_GET["stuff"]`. What else would you like me to help you with? Happy to help. 

Comment: sorry i tried that and i returned me with the error of missing token )

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot please? Looks like you a missing a `)`

Comment: $("#footer .$_GET["value1"]").load("footer.php?stuff=value1");

Comment: Uhhh... I told that should be in the PHP not in HTML.

Comment: Can you tell me what you wanna pass or what you want to do for the SQL statement?

Comment: I have updated the statement my overall goal is to have 4 boxes originally i had 4 different statements to return 4 different results but i can shrink this to 1 query if using ajax but im not sure how i would output the different results into the different boxes e.g. value1 box 1, value 2 box2 and so on

Comment: Ahhh... Alright... In that case, we can use the jQuery.each function instead. Can you post the 4 box HTML? Edit your question and add the code.

Comment: updated to include the 4 box method that i was using

Comment: Give me a few mins, I'll refactor the code and let you know in few mins.  I'm working on an efficient solution for you.

Comment: @a.parkes Checking now.

Comment: @a.parkes Check the answer.

Comment: that seems to load the data, I have added the PHP code in between HTML tags in footer.php the boxes all show in the main page now but i cant get them to format inline-block when the same code from footer.php is pasted into the main page it displays correctly inline

Comment: the mysql data display outside the box at the bottom

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i hadn't placed the script inside the footer div

Comment: @a.parkes Ah... Hope you have sorted it out.